# Chrome opens a PHP file as HTML but another one located in another folder as plain text

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, firefox

Im working on a project which uses PHP and HTML to work, mostly HTML and CSS but I like to keep my files with a PHP extension even if they don't have any PHP code in it for future updates (Just in case).

Anyway, I dont really want a Wamp server in my Windows PC because I already have Lamp in an ubuntu server netbook and I dont really need a full server just to create some simple stuff in this one (that is what I am using it for).

It happens that I edit my stuff I try it in Chrome and Firefox to see if its all good before I upload it into my server but then I get this: One of the PHP files opens correctly as if it was an HTML file but then another one opens like plain text, my question is: What does this mean?. Am I missing something somewhere or is this just a normal behaviour with the browser's attempt to recognize the file as a proper HTML file?

This is the content to the file (Index.php):
http://www.pastebin.ca/2827205

Comment: check if both have `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<html>..</html>` tags.

Comment: Yes, that is why Im completely losing my head over it, theyre practically the same file (and both have the proper tags), I just removed some content from the other one and its showing plain text now.

Comment: maybe you could show us the content of the files?

Comment: can you paste the page ? http://pastebin.com/

Comment: sure, should I quote em out or should I upload em somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for the link, Ill post it in pastebin.com.

Comment: The link to pastebin.com isn't currently working to me, I uploaded it here! http://www.pastebin.ca/2827205

Comment: It works for me, I see the code rendered as a webpage and not the code itself. Try reinstalling Chrome if it only happens in this browser

Comment: did you save the file with a PHP extension and it worked?

Comment: yes I did that and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your file on a PHP server to execute it by calling them with your browser `http://localhost/myfile.php`

If you directly open a local PHP file in your browser `file:///C:/Users/MyUsername/myfile.php`, without PHP server, it will just read it, and not execute it. It won't work

I guess the one that opens like a normal HTML file (as you said) contains only HTML code (your Index.php ?) so your browser knows how to parse it.
And the one that opens like a plain text file contains php or other code.

Edit : I 've read your question another time and saw :

> It happens that I edit my stuff I try it in Chrome and Firefox to see
>   if its all good before I upload it into my server

I confirme what i said, you need to install a WAMP on your PC because it's impossible to execute and test your PHP code without it as the browser can't do it

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a language that is processed on the server. This is why you require a PHP server installed in order to run PHP files. You can't open .php files directly in your browser from your desktop.

Comment: he can if they only include html.

Comment: I just said I did open another PHP file with my browsers and it showed the webpage perfectly fine. Its just this one another that shows all as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

only reason if it open as plain text file :

if the page has `.php` extension and inside the server (`LAMP` / `WAMP`), then in your code, you forgot to enclose them inside PHP tags :

```
<?php 
  //code here
?>
```

Because of absence of the tags, the page is being considered as noraml HTML, hence plain text

Answer (score 0):

try placing these on top of your file

```
<?php
header("content-type: text/html");
?>
```

this will make sure that server returns text/html content

Comment: Sadly, I'm running my file locally and not in a PHP server so no PHP code would do anything. I don't think this would fix it.